# Cannot add users to database via registration form

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a registration form that requires a user to input data into some fields such as username, passowrd, email, firstName, lastName. I am trying to store the information a user enters into my mongoDB database but it is not working. The error I am getting is: 
TypeError: UserDB.insert is not a function

profileController -

```
router.post('/register', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
  UserDB.insert(req.body.userID, req.body.username, req.body.password, req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName, req.body.email);
  res.redirect('login');
});
```

register.ejs -

```
</section>
        <form action='/register' method='POST'>
          <p><b>Username:</b></p>
          <input type="text" name='username'><br>

          <p><b>Password:</b></p>
          <input type="password" name='password'><br>

          <p><b>Email:</b></p>
          <input type="email" name='email'><br>

          <p><b>First Name:</b></p>
          <input type="text" name='firstName'><br>

          <p><b>Last Name:</b></p>
          <input type="text" name='lastName'><br>

          <br>
          <input type="submit" value='Submit'>
        </form>
      </form>
```

UserDB -

```
var userdbSchema = new Schema({
  userID: {type: String, required: true},
  username: {type: String, required: true},
  password: {type: String, required: true},
  firstName: {type: String, required: true},
  lastName: {type: String, required: true},
  email: {type: String, required: true},
},{collection: 'User'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userdbSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `UserDB.create` instead of `UserDB.insert` with [mongoose models](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#constructing-documents)

The syntax is also different. You should pass an object instead of the list of parameters:

```
router.post('/register', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
  UserDB.insert({
    userID: req.body.userID,
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password,
    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    email: req.body.email
  });
  res.redirect('login');
});
```

You may also consider handling the success and error cases in the callback of the `insert` function

Answer (score 0):

You are using mongoose to interact with Mongodb. There is no 'insert' method there you would have to use create or save method to save your changes. Refer https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

Code would look something like below:

```
UserDB.create({
  userID:req.body.userID,
  username:req.body.username
}).then(()=>{})
```

As request.body parameters have same name as mongoose model you can do this as well

```
UserDB.create(req.body).then(()=>{})
```